# Getting Not Found failures accessing protected Spring Boot resources

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a small test Spring Boot application that includes a controller that contains a simple service. The service is just a test service that causes the browser to display some HTML, as shown below:

```
@RestController
public class TestController
{
   @GetMapping("/testserv")
   public String getUserInformation()
   {
      return("<p>User authenticated!</p>");
   }
}
```

I also have a configuration class designed to require a user to authenticate in order to access the service. The intent is to make all other services in the application accessible without logging in, while accessing /testserv requires login:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class TestSecure extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecure) throws Exception
   {
      httpSecure.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/testserv").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
   }
}
```

If I run my application without TestSecure class, I can access the /testserv service without problems. However, when I put in the TestSecure class, I get 404 Not Found failures trying to access the service.

I did some more testing. I found that what seems to cause the Not Found failures is the line:

```
                .antMatchers("/testserv").authenticated()
```

If I comment out that line I can access /testserv. With that line in there, the application suddenly cannot find the /testserv service and generates the 404 Not Found failures.

I believe I have done everything required in order for this to work, but perhaps I am missing something? Can anyone tell me why using antMatchers() would cause a service to be not found? How can I get proper access to this service?

Comment: I assume you have ` @GetMapping("/testserv")` as annotation on request method instead of `@GetMapping("testserv")`?

Comment: OOPS. It looks like I did a typo. The actual code should be: @GetMapping("/testserv"). I will correct this.

Comment: The bad code has been corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are missing `@RequestMapping` for the controller. I think just adding that annotation should get your code working.

**Updated based on OP comment**
You should also use `.formLogin()` in order to show the login form

Comment: A properly defined RequestMapping() annotation is pretty much the equivalent of a GetMapping() annotation. Nevertheless, I did switch to using it just to see if things would change. They did: the error I get now is a 403 forbidden failure. Isn't that supposed to cause a login page to come up???

Comment: You have not added `.formLogin()` in the configuration. "A properly defined RequestMapping() annotation is pretty much the equivalent of a GetMapping() annotation" - right but, the controller needs to have a request mapping as well

Comment: Actually: the formLogin() was the answer. My auth system works properly now.

Comment: Updated answer based on comment